# Hot reloading in Docker container stops working after a while

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, dockerfile, hot-reload

**Background**

We use Docker to containerize a Vue.js app and mount a volume with the source code.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:13.8-alpine
RUN yarn install && \
    apk add --no-cache git
COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ['/bin/sh', 'start_compose.sh']
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app:delegated
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    command: ['/bin/sh', 'start_compose.sh']
```

start_compose.sh

```
yarn install
npm rebuild node-sass
yarn serve
```

**Problem**

Hot reloading works generally, and code changes are usually immediately reflected in the browser.

But very often after a while, hot reloading stops working, and the code changes are not reflected in the browser.

Stopping and restarting the container fixes the issue for a while.

**Question**

What might be causing this problem and what is the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding watchOptions to vue.config.js seems to help.

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000,
    },
  },
};
```

I am still testing to see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be in `webpack.config.js`? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptions

Answer (score 0):

In several cases, this have more sense like a node issue than docker issue. When you stop and restart the container, node is reloading... I think that node reloading is that is doing hot reloading works again.

But there is some striking mounting way, "delegated". This could lead to inconsistency between host volume (when you are editing your code) and the container view. Try changing it with "consistent".

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/#tuning-with-consistent-cached-and-delegated-configurations

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I use `delegated` to improve performance, as I do not need perfect consistency. But you may be right that the issue has more to do with Node.js (or perhaps Vue.js or something else) than with Docker. Adding `watchOptions` seems to help.